# How to calculate a (ranged) histogram of a CV_32FC1 cv::GpuMat image in OpenCV 3.4.7

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to calculate a (ranged) histogram of a cv::GpuMat image of type CV_32FC1 using OpenCV 3.4.7. Speed optimization is my major concern.

I read the documentation (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.7/d8/d0e/group__cudaimgproc__hist.html) of histogram functions in the namespace cv::cuda and found that, given the cv::GpuMat image were integer valued of type CV_8U, CV_16U, or CV_16S, cv::cuda::histRange would be the function of choice. What would be the analogous way for a floating point valued cv::GpuMat image of type CV_32FC1?

The only way I can think of is to either download the data to CPU memory, do the CPU variant cv::histRange (which supports cv::Mat of type CV_32F), and upload back to GPU memory or to do a quantization (scaling) and type conversion on GPU memory.

Is there a way to circumvent the overhead?

Comment: You could check out the implementation on github, copy the source code of the function and modify it for float types. The code should be fairly similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @timo for your comment and thanks @Gehová for your answer.

After reading into the source code as @timo suggested I found out that CV_32F is supported albeit it's not stated in the documentation.

Suppose you have some `cv::cuda::GpuMat image_gpu` of type `CV_32FC1`, e.g. created by

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat image_gpu(cv::Size(image_height, image_width), CV_32FC1);
```

then you can straight forwardly calculate a ranged histogram. I give an example which detects minimal and maximal value of (non-constantly valued) image_gpu at the device and downloads those two values to the host, creates an evenly distributed binning vector between min and max at the host, uploads that binning vector to the device and then calculates the ranged histogram at the device using cv::cuda::histRange().

```
// set number of bins
int num_bins = 100;

// detect min and max of image_gpu
double min_val, max_val;
cv::cuda::minMax(image_gpu, &min_val, &max_val);

// create binning vector at host
float bin_width = static_cast<float>(max_val - min_val) / num_bins;
cv::Mat_<float> bin_edges(1, num_bins + 1);
for (int bin_index = 0; bin_index < num_bins + 1; bin_index++)
{
    bin_edges.at<float>(0, bin_index) = static_cast<float>(min_val) + bin_index * bin_width;
}
// make the histogram calculation inclusive regarding the range [min_val, max_val]
bin_edges.at<float>(0, num_bins) += 1E-08F;

// upload binning vector from host to device
cv::cuda::GpuMat bin_edges_gpu;
bin_edges_gpu.create(1, num_bins + 1, CV_32FC1);
bin_edges_gpu.upload(bin_edges, cuda_stream);
cuda_stream.waitForCompletion();

cv::cuda::GpuMat absolute_histogram_gpu;
absolute_histogram_gpu.create(1, num_bins, CV_32SC1);

// calculate the absolute histogram of image_gpu at the device using OpenCV's cuda implementation
cv::cuda::histRange(image_gpu, absolute_histogram_gpu, bin_edges_gpu, cuda_stream);
cuda_stream.waitForCompletion();

// download the absolute histogram of image_gpu from device to host
cv::Mat_<int32_t> absolute_histogram(1, num_bins);
absolute_histogram_gpu.download(absolute_histogram, cuda_stream);
cuda_stream.waitForCompletion();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a wrapper for the function [nppiHistogramRange_32f_C1R](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/group__image__histogramrange.html). You can read the code for the opencv function you already mentioned.